# export results from jq to csv

Tags: json, csv, jq

I'm having the following dataset which I'd like to export into a CSV:

**Dataset:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "activeFindings": {
      "findings": [
        {
          "findingId": "risk#80703",
          "accountId": "00000000-000000-0000000-000000",
          "products": [
            "GWSERVER01"
          ],
          "findingDisplayName": "risk#80703",
          "severity": "CRITICAL",
          "findingDescription": "PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.",
          "findingImpact": "Potential ESXi host crash",
          "recommendations": [
            "This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523)",
            "This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804)"
          ],
          "kbLinkURLs": [
            "https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703"
          ],
          "recommendationsVCF": [
            "This issue is resolved with VMware Cloud Foundation 4.1"
          ],
          "kbLinkURLsVCF": [
            "https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703"
          ],
          "categoryName": "Storage",
          "findingTypes": [
            "UPGRADE"
          ],
          "firstObserved": 1629806351877,
          "totalAffectedObjectsCount": 12,
          "affectedObjects": [
            {
              "sourceName": "GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectName": "server01.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectType": "ESX",
              "version": "6.7.0",
              "buildNumber": "17499825",
              "solutionTags": [],
              "firstObserved": 1629806351877
            },
            {
              "sourceName": "GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectName": "server02.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectType": "ESX",
              "version": "6.7.0",
              "buildNumber": "17499825",
              "solutionTags": [],
              "firstObserved": 1629806351877
            },
            {
              "sourceName": "GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectName": "server03.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectType": "ESX",
              "version": "6.7.0",
              "buildNumber": "17499825",
              "solutionTags": [],
              "firstObserved": 1629806351877
            },
            {
              "sourceName": "GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectName": "server04.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectType": "ESX",
              "version": "6.7.0",
              "buildNumber": "17499825",
              "solutionTags": [],
              "firstObserved": 1629806351877
            },
            {
              "sourceName": "GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectName": "server05.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectType": "ESX",
              "version": "6.7.0",
              "buildNumber": "17499825",
              "solutionTags": [],
              "firstObserved": 1629806351877
            },
            {
              "sourceName": "GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectName": "server06.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectType": "ESX",
              "version": "6.7.0",
              "buildNumber": "17499825",
              "solutionTags": [],
              "firstObserved": 1629806351877
            },
            {
              "sourceName": "GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectName": "server07.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectType": "ESX",
              "version": "6.7.0",
              "buildNumber": "17499825",
              "solutionTags": [],
              "firstObserved": 1629806351877
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "totalRecords": 1,
      "timeTaken": 56
    }
  }
}
{
  "data": {
    "activeFindings": {
      "findings": [
        {
          "findingId": "risk#80703",
          "accountId": "00000000-000000-0000000-000000",
          "products": [
            "GWSERVER02.corp.contoso.org"
          ],
          "findingDisplayName": "risk#80703",
          "severity": "CRITICAL",
          "findingDescription": "PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.",
          "findingImpact": "Potential ESXi host crash",
          "recommendations": [
            "This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523)",
            "This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804)"
          ],
          "kbLinkURLs": [
            "https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703"
          ],
          "recommendationsVCF": [
            "This issue is resolved with VMware Cloud Foundation 4.1"
          ],
          "kbLinkURLsVCF": [
            "https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703"
          ],
          "categoryName": "Storage",
          "findingTypes": [
            "UPGRADE"
          ],
          "firstObserved": 1635968448112,
          "totalAffectedObjectsCount": 2,
          "affectedObjects": [
            {
              "sourceName": "GWSERVER02.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectName": "server10.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectType": "ESX",
              "version": "6.7.0",
              "buildNumber": "17167734",
              "solutionTags": [],
              "firstObserved": 1635968448112
            },
            {
              "sourceName": "GWSERVER02.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectName": "server11.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectType": "ESX",
              "version": "6.7.0",
              "buildNumber": "17167734",
              "solutionTags": [],
              "firstObserved": 1635968448112
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "totalRecords": 1,
      "timeTaken": 51
    }
  }
}
```

**And header would be as follow:**

```
"Finding Id","Issue Description","Risk if no Action Taken","Severity","Recommendations","Source Name","Object Name","Object Type","Host Version","Build","First Observed","Reference"
```

**Header keys mapping as follow:**

- Finding Id = findingId
- Issue Description = findingDescription
- Risk if no Action Taken = findingImpact
- Severity = severity
- Recommendations = recommendations
- Source Name = sourceName
- Object Name = objectName
- Object Type = objectType
- Host Version = version
- Build = buildNumber
- First Observed = firstObserved
- Reference = kbLinkURLs

Unfortunately, we have to perform an API call per each finding & product (eg: we're not able to pull all the findings for all products at once - the API does not allow us to perform such query and thus, we have to make several calls to get all the findings with its associated objects.)

With that said, what would be the preferred approach to export the data into a csv ? Would using jq's @CSV work though we would have to loop through several nodes ?

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

---

Note 1:
A stripped version of the dataset as requested by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)

```
{
  "data": {
    "activeFindings": {
      "findings": [
        {
          "findingId": "risk#80703",
          "accountId": "00000000-000000-0000000-000000",
          "products": [
            "GWSERVER01"
          ],
          "findingDisplayName": "risk#80703",
          "severity": "CRITICAL",
          "findingDescription": "PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.",
          "findingImpact": "Potential ESXi host crash",
          "recommendations": [
            "This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523)",
            "This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804)"
          ],
          "kbLinkURLs": [
            "https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703"
          ],
          "recommendationsVCF": [
            "This issue is resolved with VMware Cloud Foundation 4.1"
          ],
          "kbLinkURLsVCF": [
            "https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703"
          ],
          "categoryName": "Storage",
          "findingTypes": [
            "UPGRADE"
          ],
          "firstObserved": 1629806351877,
          "totalAffectedObjectsCount": 12,
          "affectedObjects": [
            {
              "sourceName": "GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectName": "server01.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectType": "ESX",
              "version": "6.7.0",
              "buildNumber": "17499825",
              "solutionTags": [],
              "firstObserved": 1629806351877
            },
            {
              "sourceName": "GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectName": "server02.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectType": "ESX",
              "version": "6.7.0",
              "buildNumber": "17499825",
              "solutionTags": [],
              "firstObserved": 1629806351877
            },
          ]
        }
      ],
      "totalRecords": 1,
      "timeTaken": 56
    }
  }
}
{
  "data": {
    "activeFindings": {
      "findings": [
        {
          "findingId": "risk#80703",
          "accountId": "00000000-000000-0000000-000000",
          "products": [
            "GWSERVER02.corp.contoso.org"
          ],
          "findingDisplayName": "risk#80703",
          "severity": "CRITICAL",
          "findingDescription": "PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.",
          "findingImpact": "Potential ESXi host crash",
          "recommendations": [
            "This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523)",
            "This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804)"
          ],
          "kbLinkURLs": [
            "https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703"
          ],
          "recommendationsVCF": [
            "This issue is resolved with VMware Cloud Foundation 4.1"
          ],
          "kbLinkURLsVCF": [
            "https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703"
          ],
          "categoryName": "Storage",
          "findingTypes": [
            "UPGRADE"
          ],
          "firstObserved": 1635968448112,
          "totalAffectedObjectsCount": 2,
          "affectedObjects": [
            {
              "sourceName": "GWSERVER02.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectName": "server10.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectType": "ESX",
              "version": "6.7.0",
              "buildNumber": "17167734",
              "solutionTags": [],
              "firstObserved": 1635968448112
            },
            {
              "sourceName": "GWSERVER02.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectName": "server11.corp.contoso.org",
              "objectType": "ESX",
              "version": "6.7.0",
              "buildNumber": "17167734",
              "solutionTags": [],
              "firstObserved": 1635968448112
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "totalRecords": 1,
      "timeTaken": 51
    }
  }
}
```

And the resulted CSV file:

```
"Finding Id","Issue Description","Risk if no Action Taken","Severity","Recommendations","Source Name","Object Name","Object Type","Host Version","Build","First Observed","Reference"
"risk#80703","PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.","Potential ESXi host crash","CRITICAL","This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804);This issue is resolved with VMware Cloud Foundation 4.1","GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org","server01.corp.contoso.org","HostSystem","6.7.0","17499825","1629806351877","https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703"
"risk#80703","PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.","Potential ESXi host crash","CRITICAL","This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804);This issue is resolved with VMware Cloud Foundation 4.1","GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org","server02.corp.contoso.org","HostSystem","6.7.0","17499825","1629806351877","https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703"
"risk#80703","PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.","Potential ESXi host crash","CRITICAL","This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804);This issue is resolved with VMware Cloud Foundation 4.1","GWSERVER02.corp.contoso.org","server10.corp.contoso.org","HostSystem","6.7.0","17167734","1635968448112","https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703"
"risk#80703","PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.","Potential ESXi host crash","CRITICAL","This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804);This issue is resolved with VMware Cloud Foundation 4.1","GWSERVER02.corp.contoso.org","server11.corp.contoso.org","HostSystem","6.7.0","17167734","1635968448112","https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703"
```

Comment: For the list-valued object values, how do you want to represent the contents in a single CSV field? And for the fields that occur for multiple `affectedObjects` values, do you want them in a single record, or do you want one record per affected object?

Comment: Can you provide a slightly smaller input (two affected objects per record would suffice) along with the expected CSV file?

Comment: edited the original post to include a stripped version of the dataset and the expected CSV file. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would combine jq with [spyql](https://github.com/dcmoura/spyql), here's how:

```
jq -c '.data.activeFindings.findings[]' full_sample.json | spyql "SELECT json->findingId AS 'Finding Id', json->findingDescription  AS 'Issue Description', json->findingImpact AS 'Risk if no Action Taken', json->severity AS Severity, ';'.join(json->recommendations) AS Recommendations, json->affectedObjects->sourceName AS 'Source Name', json->affectedObjects->objectName AS 'Object Name', json->affectedObjects->objectType AS 'Object Type', json->affectedObjects->version AS 'Host Version', json->affectedObjects->buildNumber AS Build, json->affectedObjects->firstObserved AS 'First Observed', ';'.join(json->kbLinkURLsVCF) AS Reference FROM json EXPLODE json->affectedObjects TO csv"      
Finding Id,Issue Description,Risk if no Action Taken,Severity,Recommendations,Source Name,Object Name,Object Type,Host Version,Build,First Observed,Reference
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server01.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,1629806351877,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server02.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,1629806351877,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server03.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,1629806351877,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server04.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,1629806351877,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server05.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,1629806351877,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server06.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,1629806351877,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server07.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,1629806351877,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER02.corp.contoso.org,server10.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17167734,1635968448112,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER02.corp.contoso.org,server11.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17167734,1635968448112,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
```

I am using jq to extract the part of the JSON we need, while compressing the output to JSON lines (required by spyql). Then, spyql takes care of the rest, namely joining arrays (expressions are python with some optional syntax sugar), renaming columns and generating the CSV.

If you want to convert the `firstObserved` timestamp to datetime you can do it like this (assuming UTC timestamp):

```
$ jq -c '.data.activeFindings.findings[]' full_sample.json | spyql "SELECT json->findingId AS 'Finding Id', json->findingDescription  AS 'Issue Description', json->findingImpact AS 'Risk if no Action Taken', json->severity AS Severity, ';'.join(json->recommendations) AS Recommendations, json->affectedObjects->sourceName AS 'Source Name', json->affectedObjects->objectName AS 'Object Name', json->affectedObjects->objectType AS 'Object Type', json->affectedObjects->version AS 'Host Version', json->affectedObjects->buildNumber AS Build, datetime.utcfromtimestamp(json->affectedObjects->firstObserved/1000) AS 'First Observed', ';'.join(json->kbLinkURLsVCF) AS Reference FROM json EXPLODE json->affectedObjects TO csv" 
Finding Id,Issue Description,Risk if no Action Taken,Severity,Recommendations,Source Name,Object Name,Object Type,Host Version,Build,First Observed,Reference
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server01.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,2021-08-24 11:59:11.877000,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server02.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,2021-08-24 11:59:11.877000,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server03.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,2021-08-24 11:59:11.877000,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server04.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,2021-08-24 11:59:11.877000,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server05.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,2021-08-24 11:59:11.877000,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server06.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,2021-08-24 11:59:11.877000,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER01.corp.contoso.org,server07.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17499825,2021-08-24 11:59:11.877000,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER02.corp.contoso.org,server10.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17167734,2021-11-03 19:40:48.112000,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
risk#80703,PSOD with re-formatting a valid dedup metadata block.,Potential ESXi host crash,CRITICAL,This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 6.7 upgrade to Patch 05 (17700523);This issue is resolved in VMware ESXi 7.0 upgrade to Update 1 (16850804),GWSERVER02.corp.contoso.org,server11.corp.contoso.org,ESX,6.7.0,17167734,2021-11-03 19:40:48.112000,https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/80703
```

If you don't need millisecond precision in your datetime you can use integer division (i.e. `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(json->affectedObjects->firstObserved//1000)`).

Disclaimer: I am the author of spyql

Comment: if you need to convert the `firstObserved` to a datetime you can use: `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(json->affectedObjects->firstObserved)`. I am assuming UTC timestamp. More datetime methods here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Thank you @daniel-c.-moura ! I have tried your suggestion, but am I getting an error. Please have a look [here](https://pastebin.com/bvxxW0W4). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @Nebukazar , since the timestamp is in milliseconds and the function expects epoch in seconds you need to divide by 1000. I updated the answer to include this.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much @Daniel-C.-Moura

Answer (score 0):

You can apply **@csv** at the last part after removing the yielded ***null*** values through use of ***`delpaths([path(.[] | select(.==null))])`*** in order to prevent generating successive redundant commas such as

```
jq -r '.data.activeFindings.findings[] 
       | [.findingId , .findingDescription, .findingImpact, .severity, (.recommendations | join(",")) , .affectedObjects[].sourceName, .affectedObjects[].objectName, .affectedObjects[].objectType, .affectedObjects[].version, .affectedObjects[].buildNumber, .firstObserved, (.kbLinkURLs | join(",")) ] 
       | delpaths([path(.[] | select(.==null))]) 
       | @csv'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vMiy3JXw3x)</kbd>

Comment: Is `| to_entries[] | .value` necessary ? You can just do `.data.activeFindings.findings[] | [.findingId,...]`

Comment: I've been trying your suggestion @barbaros-Özhan but the following fields won't get populated (eg: they are reverting back to null): Source Name, Object Name, Object Type, Host Version, Build and wil throw an error: jq: error (at <stdin>:4): null (null) has no keys (probably due to some formatting issues ?)

Comment: @Nebukazar I used exactly *your second JSON* within the demo, except for the comma, which's removed , at line 52, column 11

Comment: exactly, you're right @Philippe , this method is better, thanks.

Comment: For some reasons, Source Name, Object Name, Object Type, Host Version and Build entries will all return no values. I am providing you with the [JSON and jq query](https://jqplay.org/s/_w_wZSWgAM) I am working with. FYI- I have replaced the findingID with findingDisplayName

Comment: Hi @Nebukazar , seems that I missed that part. Fixed within the answer. You can [check out](https://jqplay.org/s/Pv_g-siJBZ) for your new test case.

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros-Özhan ! I just found out that some of the entries do not exist for some of the risks (eg: vSAN-Diskfailures-KB#2108691 does not have any version nor buildNumber) and as a result, it is mixing up the CSV file (eg: values are being shifted to the left - for instance, the FirstObserved value will be filled under Host Version). Would there be a way to simply put a null value if the key does not exist ? I believe the first jq cmd you provided in your initial response was taking care of that part ?

Comment: you're welcome @Nebukazar . In that case you can use this `.data.activeFindings.findings | to_entries[] | .value | [ .findingId , .findingDescription, .findingImpact, .severity, (.recommendations | join(",")) , .affectedObjects[].sourceName, .affectedObjects[].objectName, .affectedObjects[].objectType, .affectedObjects[].version, .affectedObjects[].buildNumber, .firstObserved, (.kbLinkURLs | join(",")) ] | @csv` adapted from the first response of mine.

Comment: one last question! would there be a way to automatically convert the firstObserved value (which is in unix time) to say an excel date (eg: value / 86400)+DATE(1970,1,1)) through jq ?

Comment: My apologies! But though the following code will work for empty value, it won't create a line per each sub affectedObjects. It will append them all in one line `.data.activeFindings.findings | to_entries[] | .value | [ .findingId , .findingDescription, .findingImpact, .severity, (.recommendations | join(",")) , .affectedObjects[].sourceName, .affectedObjects[].objectName, .affectedObjects[].objectType, .affectedObjects[].version, .affectedObjects[].buildNumber, .firstObserved, (.kbLinkURLs | join(",")) ] | @csv` - see 
[here](https://jqplay.org/s/QK5Rk57TdI)

Comment: well, it should already generate successive commas for null values @Nebukazar

Comment: It does; however, the problem seems to be where there are multiple occurrence of affectedObjects within the same findingId, it won't split them up into separate lines. Instead, it just append them all within the same line ?